# Struggling to understand groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to understand how the parameters for df.groupby works. I have the following code:

```
df = pd.read_sql(query_cnxn)
codegroup = df.groupby(['CODE'])
```

I then attempt a for loop as follows:

```
for code in codegroup:
    dfsize = codegroup.size()
    dfmax = codegroup['ID'].max()
    dfmin = codegroup['ID'].min()
    result = ((dfmax-dfmin)-dfsize)

    if result == 1:
        df2 = df2.append(itn)
    else:
        df3 = df3.append(itn)
```

I'm trying to iterate over each unique code. Does the for loop understand that i'm trying to loop through each code based on the above? Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, you are iterating as `code` but in your loop you are using `codegroup`. Second, the `df.groupby` will return an iterator that emits a tuple `(k, g)` at each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `groupby` returns an iterator that emits the key of the iterating group and group df as a tuple. You can perform your `max` and `min` operation on the group as:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 'b': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})

In [3]: for k, g in df.groupby('a'):
   ...:     print(g['b'].max())
   ...:
5
8
```

You can also get the min-max directly as df using `agg`:

```
In [4]: df.groupby('a')['b'].agg(['max', 'min'])
Out[4]:
   max  min
a
0    5    3
1    8    6
```